# Scraping specific sports data SELENIUM/BS4

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

am trying to scrape data from this page https://www.flashscore.pl/druzyna/ajax/8UOvIwnb/tabela

Q1:I created this code, but I don't know how to extract data for AJAX team only. The data is to be saved as a list. later they will be saved to csv file. In addition, I am not interested, for example, the sign "?" how to exclude it? I'll be grateful for your help.

Q2: How can i separate anserw for "AJAX" e.g with ";" Ajax;18;13;3;2;56:4;42;?;W;W;P;W;W;

CODE

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import requests
from time import sleep
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.flashscore.pl/druzyna/ajax/8UOvIwnb/tabela/")
sleep(10)
page = driver.page_source
soup = BS(page,'html.parser')
content3 = soup.find('div',{'class':'ui-table__body'})
content_list3 = content.find_all('div',{'class':'tableCellFormIcon tableCellFormIcon--TBD'})

for i in content3:
    print(i.text.split()[0])
```

RESULTS

```
1.PSV18141346:2443?WWWWR
2.Ajax18133256:442?WWPWW
3.Feyenoord18123342:1739?WPRWW
4.Vitesse18103525:2533?WRWWR
5.Alkmaar18102635:2332?WWWWW
6.Twente1895428:2232?RWWWR
7.Utrecht1885533:2329?RRRPW
8.Cambuur1891832:3928?RPWPW
9.Nijmegen1874724:2625?WWPPP
10.Heerenveen1874720:2525?PWRWR
11.G.A.
12.Groningen1847720:2719?PPRRW
13.Heracles18531021:2618?RWPPP
14.Willem
15.Waalwijk1837819:3016?RPPWR
16.Sparta
17.Sittard18341119:4613?PRWPP
18.Zwolle1813149:326?PPPRR
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add it to a list:

```py
res = []
for i in content3:
    line = i.text.split()[0]
    print(line)
    res.append(line)
```

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html -

> list.append(x) Add an item to the end of the list. Equivalent to
> a[len(a):] = [x].

---

to replace the "?" add this:

```
line = line.replace("?", "")
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace -

> str.replace(old, new[, count])
> Return a copy of the string with all
> occurrences of substring old replaced by new. If the optional argument
> count is given, only the first count occurrences are replaced.

To check if line contains "Ajax":

```
if "Ajax" in line:
    print(line)
```

Comment: thanks. But how i can print result for specyfic team ' AJAX' . When i put it on list i can print e.g only third elelemnt ? How i can do that ?

Comment: @Piotr See my edit

Comment: Thanks. Did you know how can i seperate results. e.g  2.;Ajax;18;1;3;3;2;56:44;2;?;W;W;P;W;W

Comment: @Piotr Please approve/vote up the answer and ask another question if you need.

Comment: Ok i Approve vote and add Q2 on main topic. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Added regular expressions and sorted "Ajax":

```
import re 

res = []
for i in content3:
    line = i.text.split()[0]
    if re.search('Ajax', line):
        line = line.replace("?", "")
        res.append(line)

print(res)
```

Comment: nice thanks. How can i separate results with ',' ?